# Unable to go back to original References in Visual Studio 2013 C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reference

Yesterday, when I was adding references to a C# project I accidentally navigated out of the folder containing all of the .dll files containing the references.

I can not figure out how to navigate back to the folder containing the .dll files now.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. How can I solve this problem?

Sorry, clearly my question was ambiguous. This is the issue:

When I click the Browse Button in the Reference Manager, it displays my download folder (sorry I don't have enough reputation to post a screenshot). What I want to do is to navigate back to the folder or directory containing the .dll files that I can add as references. This folder was present when I first opened up the Browse button, and before I accidentally navigated away.

Comment: what do you mean by navigated out? you mean you closed the solution browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

In this case just look where the other references came from by opening the properties of a reference (theres a property path) and browse to this folder again and you are there...

Comment: Sorry, I am talking about adding references, not opening the solution explorer. See my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on "References" in the Solution Explorer, under your project. Choose "Add Reference."

Comment: I know how to add references; what happened was that I accidentally left the folder or directory containing the .dll files that I could add as references.

Answer (score 0):

If you were browsing through the OS folders, using the "Browse" feature of the Reference Manager, this navigation is handled by the OS (Windows), and not the IDE (Visual Studio).

You'll have to approach this from a Windows file explorer standpoint, or something similar. A possibility could be looking to see if you have a "Recent Places" search folder, or perhaps doing a search based on time/date accessed.